# capture data based on the values in URL

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to write a function in JS, if URL contains utm_campaign value, then send it, otherwise leave it blank.

For example i have this link.

```
http://example.com/home/?utm_campaign=mycampaign_2016_en&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_content=home
```

I want my function to return "campaign_2016_en" in my script. And when the utm_campaign parameter is not available return blank. But note that the URL and the values would not be the same always.

I am not sure where to start. Appreciate all the helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Call above function, this function will return empty string if query string value is not available.

```
getParameterByName('utm_campaign', 'http://example.com/home/?utm_campaign=mycampaign_2016_en&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_content=home');
```

Or just pass query string param name. It will use `window` object to read url

```
getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
```

**JS Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/4199/

Comment: do you know how can i test this on jsfiddle?